# C# "using" blocks

Tags: c#, design-patterns, stream, using, streamreader

I've got something like the code below...someone here mentioned that the WebClient, Stream, and StreamReader objects could all benefit from using blocks.  Two easy questions:

1: How would this little snippet look with using blocks? I've no problem with doing my own research so resource links are fine but it'd be quicker and easier to just see an example and I'll understand it from that.

2: I'd like to get in the habit of good coding standards, would help if I knew a little about the reasons why using blocks are better...is it just so you don't have to worry about closing or are there more reasons?  Thanks!

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(originGetterURL);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
string encryptionKey = (string)jObject["key"];
string originURL = (string)jObject["origin_url"];

stream.Close()
reader.Close()
```

Comment: sorry..looks like the code formatting kinda got mucked a bit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
using (var stream = client.OpenRead(originGetterURL))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
    var encryptionKey = (string)jObject["key"];
    var originURL = (string)jObject["origin_url"];
}
```

or simply:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var json = client.DownloadString(originGetterURL);
    var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
    var encryptionKey = (string)jObject["key"];
    var originURL = (string)jObject["origin_url"];
}
```

Comment: ah thanks, I was kinda thinking it be a bit more than that...like using reader nested in the using stream block but I guess if it's that simple...so is the main purpose of wanting to do it this way just so I don't have to worry about disposal or are there more advantages?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of the using block is to ensure that the Dispose method will be called even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @J Benjamin - disposal will always happen, this just lets you force it to happen before anything after the using block is executed

Comment: Why didn't anyone tell me I could stack usings with a single set of curly braces. Why not?!?!

Comment: @Nathan Taylor - It's just like skipping them in any other block if you're only got one line within. Personally, I find it more difficult to read, especially in this case where the OP isn't sure how to use them.

Comment: @JamesSkemp Is it the same though? Are the objects going to be disposed in the next line, or just before the outermost curly brace?

Comment: @Nathan, they will be disposed just after the closing `}` and in the inverse order of which they were instantiated.

Comment: @Darin - thanks, I really like how clever and clean it is.  And thanks all for the comments and responses.

Answer (score 5):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    // do work
}
```

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) objects.

From MSDN: **[using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)**

---

> **As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement.** The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

---

> **The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.** You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {

}
```

is the same as

```
WebClient client;
try {
    client = new WebClient();
} finally {
    if(client != null) {
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

A lot easier to use using

Answer (score 2):

Its simple :

Using `*using*` is not "good practice" as such, more a short way (syntactic sugar) of disposing objects that you **should** be disposing. Things like Files, Connections to a Database and in your case  a network.

You would do something like:

```
using(WebClient we = new WebClient))
{
//do something with 'we' here
}
```

This is basically just a shortcut for using the variable `we` normally and then calling `we.Dispose()` which does a clean up.

Syntax :

```
using (<Any class that Implements IDisposable>)
{
//use the class
}
```

Other SO questions you should see:
[What is the relationship between the using keyword and the IDisposable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544758/idisposable-vs-using-keyword)
[using various types in a using statement (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966086/using-various-types-in-a-using-statement-c)

Comment: oh boy! I didn't check your code properly, anyway, I see now a lot of other answers =P Hope mine was useful!

Answer (score 1):

using {} blocks simply call Dispose() at the closing brace--or rather, tell the Garbage Collector that it can dispose of the object. You'd use it like:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    Stream stream = client.OpenRead(originGetterURL); StreamReader reader = new  StreamReader(stream);

    JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine()); string encryptionKey = (string)jObject["key"]; string originURL = (string)jObject["origin_url"];

    stream.Close() reader.Close()
} // 'client' instance gets disposed here
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
using(Stream stream = client.OpenRead(originGetterURL))
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream) {
  JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
  string encryptionKey = (string)jObject["key"];
  string originURL = (string)jObject["origin_url"];
}
```

As for why `using` blocks are good, and better than manually calling Dispose... image if any of the code in that `using` block threw an exception before you hit the lines where you close everything? You'd essentially leak whatever unmanaged resource the IDisposable object is managing under the hood. `using` ensures that Dispose is called correctly, even in the face of an exception (by essentially injecting the appropriate try/finally block).

When possible (i.e., you don't have to preserve the lifetime of some IDisposable across scopes), you should leverage `using` blocks if for no other reason than they reduce the amount of boilerplate code you have to write in order to ensure your own code is safe and correct.

Answer (score 1):

@Darin's answer shows the code.  The reason they are good is that using blocks cause the compiler to spit out code that will automatically call "Dispose" on the object (to have it immediately release any resources it may be using) before exiting the block - even if an exception gets thrown within with the block

Answer (score 1):

`using` is equivalent to `try.. finally` so the disposer will run even if an exception is thrown within the block.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reasons for using-blocks:

- They look good
- The code inside the block often could throw exceptions. So you wold need try-finally

In the end a using-block e.g.

```
using (Somthing somthing=...)
{
    DoActions(somthing);
}
```

is identical to the followin contstruct:

```
{Somthing somthing=...
    try
    {
        DoActions(somthing);
    }
    finally
    {
        somthing.Dispose();
    }
}//the outer bracket limits the variable
```